# Grails GORM : Find All with Associations

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to get all Users in a certain age range.
I have a `User` table and a `Profile` table for each `User`.

**Minimal `User` Domain Class:**

```
class User {

  static hasOne = [profile: Profile]

}
```

**Minimal `Profile` Domain Class:**

```
class Profile {

  static belongsTo = [user: User]

  Integer age

  static constraints = {
    age(range: 18 .. 150)
  }

}
```

**Minimal `UserService` Domain Class:**

```
class UserService {

  def list() {

    def users = User.findAll{
      gender in whichGenderList
      profile.age in 18 .. 150 /* Problem */
    }

}
```

On the line with `Problem` I'm getting the following exception in browser:

```
URI /foo/browse
Class org.hibernate.QueryException
Message could not resolve property: profile_alias0 of: foo.Profile
```

**Question:**
In `UserService` how can I select from each `User`'s `Profile` table its age?

**I'm using:**

- Grails 2.4.4

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use criteria query like this:

```
 def users = User.createCriteria().list(){
     inList('gender', whichGenderList)
     profile{
          inList('age', 18 .. 150)
     }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If in doubt use HQL:

```
User.findAll(
    "from User u where u.gender in :genders and u.profile.age between :minAge and :maxAge",
    [genders: [], minAge: 18, maxAge: 150]
)
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using HQL! When I can.